# Android how to change the black default background color of the app

Tags: android, xml, colors, background-color

I tried everything that i can possibly do but it seems like it requires a different approach to change the color of the black default blackground.

Here is the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SwzX.jpg

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EE7469"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:background="#689F38"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"

        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="#689F38"/>

    <!-- ADDED SPACER VIEW  -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#689F38"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <!-- /ADDED SPACER VIEW -->

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/edit_btn"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView >
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I tried changing the background color but it's still black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#689F38"
```

So code be like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#689F38"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

If you want to change programatically use:

```
your_cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(your_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought the problem is in inflating  the view in adapter

use below code in layout inflation

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative layout or linear layout in cardview and set the width and height "match_parent" and set the cardeview color "transparent" as below

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

And set the the linear or relative layout `background #689f38`